# Show that the following is a base

Tags: general-topology

Given topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, let $Y^X$ denote the space of all continuous functions $f : X \rightarrow Y$. Given a compact set $A \subseteq X$ and an open set $B \subseteq  Y$, let $(A,B) = \{f \in Y^X \mid f[A] \subseteq B\}$.

Show that the family of sets generated by taking intersections of finite collection of sets of the form $(A,B)$ is a basis. The topology generated on $Y^X$ by this basis is called the compact-open topology; thus, sets of the form $(A,B)$ are a subbase for this topology.

Comment: A better notation for the continuous functions is $C(X,Y),$ maybe with a fancier $C.$ Using $YX$ is not typical, though use of $Y^X$ for the set of *all* functions from $X$ to $Y$ is made, at least in some logic/set theory contexts.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost nothing to prove, except that the $(A,B)$ cover $Y^X$, which is clear as $(\{p\}, Y) = Y^X$ for any $p \in X$ (a singleton is compact).

The set of finite intersections of any family is itself closed under intersections, and so the two conditions to check that a family is a base ([see here, e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology))) are easily satisfied.